# Order of infinitesimal $f(x)= x^2+9x^4+o(x^4)$, as $x\to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis

Question is order of infinitesimal wrt $x$ as $x$ approaches $0$.
I get that as $x\to 0$,  $x^4$ is negligible compared to $x^2$ but the thing is as I write the principal part should I write it like $x^2 + o(x^4)$ or $x^2 + o(x^2)$.
If second one is true, how did we get it cause we don't have the term $o(x^2)$.
In this case what should be my approach?

Thanks!

Comment: $9x^4+o(x^4)=o(x^2),$ not $o(x^4).$

Comment: To elaborate on Anne's comment: indeed, $9x^4/x^4$ does *not* tend to $0$ as $x\to0$.